# CursorAdapter showing wrong values in android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to implement a list that fetches chats from my ORM database and displays them in a list.The chats get fetched and displayed pretty neatly,but when I bring the keyboard up to type a message,the chat values in the list get jumbled.I have fetched the chat values in the ascending order of their timestamp.
This is my Adapter...

```
public class ChatsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ContactInfo contact;
    private Chat item;
    private Cursor c;
    public ChatsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery, ContactInfo contact) {
        super(context, c, false);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = context;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View v = null;
        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_IS_ME)) > 0) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.incoming_message, parent, false);
            holder._name = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
            holder._text = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder._time = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.time);
            String name = SharedPerefsUtil.getSharedPreferencesString(context, Constants.NAME, "");
            holder._name.setText(name);
            holder._time.setText(Util.getTime(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_TIME))));
            holder._text.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_TEXT)));
        } else {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.outgoing_msg, parent, false);
            holder._name = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
            holder._text = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder._time = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.time);

            holder._name.setText(contact.getName());

            holder._text.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_TEXT)));
            holder._time.setText(Util.getTime(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_TIME))));
        }
        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
        return getItemViewType(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }





    private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
        boolean type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Chat.COLMN_FROM_ME)) > 0;
        if (type) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }


    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView _name;
        public TextView _time;
        public TextView _text;
        public ImageView _image;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated..thanks in advance..

Comment: you should bind your views (calls to cursor.getString()) in `bindView` method, not in 'newView`

Comment: @pskink but bindView gets called every single time when the list is scrolled right?..will really setting values in bindView solve my problem.?

Comment: you will not know until you change your code (add Log.d statements inside newView and bindView and you will see)

Comment: @pskink alright...i set it into the newView because i have inflated two different row layouts in my..it was causing some problem in setting the values..still will try your solution..

Comment: @pskink yes..it did the trick..thanks..